# Como é ou pode ser implementada a função cond do Common Lisp?

Tags: funções, condição, switch, controle-de-fluxo, lisp

Em Common Lisp, a função `cond` pode receber pares de expressões booleanas (que julgo serem condições, ou predicados) e expressões quaisquer e avaliar uma a uma as expressões booleanas até encontrar uma verdadeira, e executar a respectiva expressão subsequente, efetivamente fornecendo a funcionalidade de um `switch-case`.

No exemplo abaixo, `t` equivale ao booleano `true`, que sempre dispara a execução da expressão subsequente, como o `else` de um `switch-case`.

```
(cond
  ((e1) (s1))
  ((e2) (s2))
  ((e3) (s3))
  ((e4) (s4))
  (t (s5)))
```

A dúvida é, sendo a Common Lisp uma linguagem minimalista e com recursos simples (ou talvez eu esteja pensando em Scheme, de qualquer forma a pergunta serve para ela também), como ela pode implementar a função `cond` de maneira a esta ter tal comportamento?

Comment: Pelo visto a resposta a isso [daria um livro](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4842-6134-7). Ou pelo menos [um longo capítulo](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4842-6134-7_3).